# Icons went missing in Windows 8 after installation of NCH Software

Tags: windows, windows-8, icons

My icons were replaced by a folder-like icon throughout after I installed NCH Software. This only happens with the following extension: .doc (opened with Kingsoft Writer), .png (opened with Windows Photo Viewer), .jpeg (Windows Photo Viewer), .rtf (opened with WordPad)

I have tried the following:

1. Rebuild the Icon Cache, twice
2. Check the file association, and there was no problem, these files were associated with the correct program.
3. Reinstalled Kingsoft Writer.
4. Ran AVAST! antivirus, no virus detected

I've also tried logging in to my other account, and view a .png file. The icon showed up perfectly fine in the alternative account.

The funny thing is, with .rtf file which also can be opened by Kingsoft Writer, when I changed .rtf file to open with Kingsoft Writer, the icon returns to normal. Then, when I changed it back to open with Wordpad, the same issue occurs again.

So the issue seems to be that certain extension, with certain combination of program, will result in the file icon being rendered strangely.

P.S. And yes, there was no issue with opening these files, they open perfectly fine. It's just the icon that bothered me.